# Executar função dentro de Data no Vue.Js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, getters-setters

Em um componente Vue.Js eu utilizo este modelo de Script como no exemplo.
Em um getter, eu inseri um return do que se recebe

```
const GetSegmento = () => (param) => {
  return (() => {
    return param
  })(param)
}
```

"Ele será evoluído conforme eu consiga fazer o que procuro aqui"

Em meu componente eu procuro poder receber o Objeto ou Valor que meu getter retorna no `data` > `segmento` onde pretendo utilizar outrora para outra coisa, o que gostaria de saber é, como consigo o retorno executado, ou só o resultado no caso ao utilizar o Getter `GetSegmento` na parte `Data`?

Caso eu coloque o `this.GetSegmento(this.$route)` dentro do `Console.log` está funcionando perfeitamente, porém gostaria de usar dentro do `Data` caso isso seja possível, claro, não sei se é possível ou como fazer.

```
export default {
  data: () => ({
    segmento: s => this.GetSegmento(this.$route)
  }),

  onIdle () {
    console.log(this.segmento)
  }
}
```

Isso é o que retorna quando eu uso da forma acima

```
ƒ segmento(s) {
  return _this.GetSegmento(_this.$route);
}
```

O objetivo real, é também saber se é possível o utilizar em uma Constant no seguinte exemplo.

```
const segmento = s => this.GetSegmento(this.$route)

export default {
    computed: {
      ...mapGetters('Modules', [ 'Segmento1', 'Segmento2' ])
  },

  onIdle () {
    console.log(this[segmento])
  }
}
```

---

### Explicação com Arquivos

O arquivo ao qual me refiro é um arquivo do tipo `.vue`, um `template` com o seguinte formato

```
<template>
  <div>{{ segmento }}</div>
</template>

<script>
  import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'

  export default {
    data: () => ({
      segmento: ''
    }),

    computed: {
      ...mapGetters('GetUm', [ 'SegmentoUm' ]),
      ...mapGetters('GetDois', [ 'SegmentoDois' ])
    },

    mounted () {
      console.log(this.SegmentoUm(this.$route)) // funciona muito bem
      console.log(this.SegmentoDois(this.$route)) // funciona muito bem
    },

    methods: {
      getSegmento () {
        this.segmento = this.SegmentoUm(this.$route.meta.segmento) // funciona também
        this.segmento = this.SegmentoDois(this.$route.meta.segmento) // funciona também
      }
    }
  }
```

A única coisa que desejo, é saber se é possível e como realizar a execução e retorno do resultado do `SegmentoUm` e ou `SegmentoDois` dentro do `data: segmento` ou dentro de um `const` fora do `export default` como no exemplo abaixo:

```
<template>
  <div>{{ segmento }}</div>
</template>

<script>
  import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'

  const segmento = this.SegmentoUm // ou aqui

  export default {
    data: () => ({
      segmento: this.SegmentoUm // ou aqui
    }),

    computed: {
      ...mapGetters('GetUm', [ 'SegmentoUm' ]),
      ...mapGetters('GetDois', [ 'SegmentoDois' ])
    },

    mounted () {
      console.log(this.SegmentoUm(this.segmento)) // então vejo aqui
    },

    methods: {
      getSegmento () {
        this.segmento = this.SegmentoUm(segmento) // ou aqui
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Só um aparte (estou ainda a ler a pergunta): o parametro `})(param)` do IIFE é desnecessário, uma vez que não estás a usar como argumento na função.

Comment: Podes mostrar o ficheiro da store desse `Modules`? A pergunta é interessante mas não está bem clara ainda...

Comment: @Sergio mas na pergunta eu não manipulei a `Store`, não preciso pegar informação da `Store`, só preciso, se possível, executar um getter no `data` ou `const`

Comment: @Sergio este `})(param)` ainda será montado, e ele será usado para um `dispatch` mais para frente

Comment: Não percebo o que queres dizer com "getter no data", por que não usas um `computed` para isso? Se perceber(mos) o problema a resposta não demora :)

Comment: @Sergio é que meu objetivo não é usar o getter no `created` ou no `mounted` e no `computed` está o getter, porém quero o executar em um `data` ou em um `const`

Comment: Oi, lamento a minha falta de tempo, li agora e ainda não percebo o que queres fazer :) Podes criar um exemplo aqui ou no jsFiddle, simples, para poder perceber melhor...?

Comment: Usa este jsFiddle se der mais jeito: https://jsfiddle.net/chrisvfritz/50wL7mdz/

Comment: Opa meu amigo @Sergio , rapaz, é quase isso que eu quero fazer https://codepen.io/flourigh/pen/vYBpgrx o problema é que eu uso mapState, mapGetters, mapMuttations, ou seja, no exemplo do link, parece funcionar como eu desejo mas não consegui fazer sendo mapGetters

Comment: É isto que procuras? https://codepen.io/sergiocrisostomo/pen/WNedXdJ?editors=1010 Sempre que usas o `mapGetters` tens de passar `store: store,` no objeto que vai ser uma instância Vue.

Comment: @Sergio então, neste formato, realmente funciona, no formato que enviei também funciona, o problema é  no formato namespace, ou seja, estou utilizando modulos separados para cada coisa, ou seja, neste fomato que enviou eu consegui fazer funcionar inclusive no exemplo que enviei, já neste formato aqui https://codepen.io/flourigh/pen/eYOyLBm - https://codepen.io/flourigh/pen/eYOyLBm.html - https://codepen.io/flourigh/pen/eYOyLBm.babel eu não consegui fazer funcionar

Comment: Nesse caso deves usar `SelectPagamento` no template onde tens `express` e nada de const ou data com o valor de express

Comment: @Sergio ali no mustashe é só um exemplo, eu quero usar como neste formato `[express]name` ou na verdade `[segmento]name` assim como eu uso se a const for fixa com uma String, não uma function, só quero chamar uma function no const e receber o resultado da function pois estou recebendo a function como na pergunta

Comment: Podes usar `SelectPagamento.name`... ou `SelectPagamento ? SelectPagamento.name : ''`. Cria um exemplo no codepen igual ao que queres mas sem funcionar que eu corrigo

Comment: @Sergio beleza, vou tentar este e te aviso ou crio o modelo que mencionou